# how to show a text when a button is clicked(button is surrounded by <span></span> tag)

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm using codeigniter and in my project i have a form where i have to rate a product and i have add star buttons like below

```
<h1>
    <div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
        <span id="span1" onclick="myFunction()">☆</span> 
        <span id="span2" onclick="myFunction()">☆</span> 
        <span id="span3" onclick="myFunction()">☆</span> 
        <span id="span4" onclick="myFunction()">☆</span>
        <span id="span5" onclick="myFunction()">☆</span>
    </div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```

what i needed to know is when i clicked 1st button(id =span1) i need to show text "Terrible",when 2nd button is clicked i need to show "Unsatisfied" and when 3rd button is clicked "satisfied" in the place where p tag is . so how can i achieve that please help me ?

Comment: which text you want to show in p tag?

Comment: I added the answer in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with

```
<h1>
  <div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
      <span id="span1" onclick="document.getElementById('rateText').innerHTML='My sample text1';"> ☆ </span>
      <span id="span2" onclick="document.getElementById('rateText').innerHTML='My sample text2';"> ☆ </span> 
      <span id="span3" onclick="document.getElementById('rateText').innerHTML='My sample text3';"> ☆ </span> 
      <span id="span4" onclick="document.getElementById('rateText').innerHTML='My sample text4';"> ☆ </span>
      <span id="span5" onclick="document.getElementById('rateText').innerHTML='My sample text5';"> ☆ </span>
    </div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<h1>
<div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
    <span onclick="myFunction(1)">☆</span> 
    <span onclick="myFunction(2)">☆</span> 
    <span onclick="myFunction(3)">☆</span> 
    <span onclick="myFunction(4)">☆</span>
    <span onclick="myFunction(5)">☆</span>
</div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```

Next with js, call myFunction(PARAM) with the param and append that on `<p></p>`

```
  function myFunction(stars){
        $('#rateText').append('nb stars : ' + stars);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Basic functionality

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pydJwp)

---

**Markup** (using `data-*` attributes)

```
<h1>
    <div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
        <span data-rating="terrible">☆</span> 
        <span data-rating="unsatisfied">☆</span> 
        <span data-rating="satisfied">☆</span> 
        <span data-rating="happy">☆</span>
        <span data-rating="delighted">☆</span>
    </div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```

*Vanilla* **JS**

```
var rating = document.getElementsByClassName('rating')[0];
var result = document.getElementById('rateText');

rating.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
   var elm = evt.target;
   if (elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'span') {
      result.textContent = elm.dataset.rating;
   }
});
```

A single event listener is attached on the wrapper elements, no need to attach an handler for each `span` element

---

### Adding a simple mouseover effect

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZeNyj)

In order to create a pure CSS mouseover effect, I inverted the order of the star elements in the markup and I visually reverted their order using `flexbox`

```
<span id="span5" data-rating="delighted">☆</span>
<span id="span4" data-rating="happy">☆</span>
<span id="span3" data-rating="satisfied">☆</span> 
<span id="span2" data-rating="unsatisfied">☆</span> 
<span id="span1" data-rating="terrible">☆</span>
```

The black star (unicode `U+2605`) is placed as the `::before` pseudoelement of each `span` element

**CSS**

```
.rating { 
   display: flex; 
   flex-flow: row-reverse; 
   justify-content: space-around; }

.rating span {
   position: relative; 
   cursor: pointer; }

.rating span:hover::before,
.rating span:hover ~ span::before {
   content: "\2605";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
}
```

As a final note I would strongly recommend  to use a `SVG` element `<use xlink:href="...">...</use>` for the stars, so you can style them by simply changing their `fill` or `stroke` property, as in the example below.

---

### SVG version

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGWOvG)

The markup of the rating is changed as described above (note: the `data-rating` attribute is now defined on the `use` element, so also the script slightly changed)

```
<span>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#star" data-rating="delighted"></use></svg>
</span>
<span>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#star" data-rating="happy"></use></svg> 
</span>
<span>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#star" data-rating="satisfied"></use></svg>
</span> 
<span>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#star" data-rating="unsatisfied"></use></svg>
</span> 
<span>
  <svg><use xlink:href="#star" data-rating="terrible"></use></svg>  
</span>
```

And in this example the styling part is done by overriding the `fill` and `stroke` properties

```
.rating use  {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #363636;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    transition: fill .33s, stroke-width .33s }

.rating span:hover use,
.rating span:hover ~ span use{
    stroke-width: 0;
    fill: #37393b; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this:

<h1>
    <div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
        <span id="span1" onclick="myFunction('one')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span2" onclick="myFunction('two')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span3" onclick="myFunction('three')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span4" onclick="myFunction('four')">☆</span>
        <span id="span5" onclick="myFunction('five')">☆</span>
    </div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```

What I understand it you have to show on which button the user has clicked, so i have passed paramerter to function like one,two, three ...

In place of that you can add your text.

you have to add a script tag like below and jquery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
         function myFunction(desc){
             $('#rateText').text(desc);
         } 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction(rating) {
  document.getElementById("rateText").innerHTML = rating;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
        <span id="span1" onclick="myFunction('Terrible')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span2" onclick="myFunction('Unsatisfied')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span3" onclick="myFunction('Satisfied')">☆</span> 
        <span id="span4" onclick="myFunction('Very Satisfied')">☆</span>
        <span id="span5" onclick="myFunction('Awesome')">☆</span>
    </div>
</h1>
<p id="rateText"></p>
```